# iptables rule not applying properly

Tags: ubuntu, iptables

I'm trying to log all pings I receive on my server.
However, it only logs pings from inside the server itself but nothing outside of it.

This is the rule I'm using: `iptables -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j LOG --log-prefix "PING_1: "`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please add result of `iptables --line-numbers -nvL` to your question. I expect there is a `DROP` or `REJECT` earlier in the list than your rule

Comment: echo-request is incoming on the host being ping'ed, and as the OP talks about logging pings he receives that is the relevant case. Like @roaima I guess the "problem" is that nothing reaches this rule because it's `DROP`'ped or `REJECT`'ed earlier.